# Jenkins Multi-Configuration Project execute concurrently on different nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have configured a multi-configuration job in the Jenkins 2.5 that executes a test suite across different configured versions of our product, and on different OS images.

The job is configured to run with different OS nodes (Windows 7, Windows 8.1, Windows 10, POS Ready 7, etc...).  On each of these OS's we then run the tests with different configurations which have to run 1 at a time.

Currently, the multi-configuration project will run each of the test scenarios sequentially across the various computers.  The job is configured with the `Execute concurrent builds if necessary` flag enabled, but the jobs do not run in parallel.

Using the node setting [Node Configuration http://i.stack.imgu](http://i.stack.imgu) for the different OS images and then a setting for the different configs, multiple executions on the same OS will run, albeit the jobs run sequentially.

I was hoping that one configuration would be run on each node concurrently so that each OS image is running one configuration.  With 4 OS's and 3 configurations, there are 12 jobs to be run.  At 1 hour each, this is 12 hours, where if the jobs ran in parallel (one on each OS) then the 3 different configurations would run, and should be done in about 3 hours total.

Ideally, the execution would be:
(Windows 7 / Config1) & (Windows 8.1 / Config1) & (Windows 10 / Config1) all running at the same time, then each OS with Config2, and then each OS with Config3.  As I indicated, even if the configs were intermixed (config1 or config2 or config3) on any of the OS's as long as each OS is running a test at the same time, and will only run 1 configuration test per OS at a time.

[image: Job Configuration Options]r.com/Qt83L.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you'd work with the [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) combined with the [Node Label Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) plugin.

It's quite simple to configure it -

1. Add new free style job - add node parameter and other required parameters. This job will be running your logic (what the multi-configuration job is running now)

[image]

2. Add new multi-job job (make sure the type you select is a multi job!)
   [image]

   - In the build section add a multi-job phase
   - Add 3 triggers to the job you created above, send each node name you're using in your multi-configuration job for each trigger, and
     the configuration you want to run. for example, you will trigger the
     job with predefined parameters to specify the node and the test
     configuration you want to run.
   - Repeat adding multi-job phases for each test configuration.

Example: 
[image]

This configuration will run 3 execution each time with each test configuration, as anything under a phase is running in parallel.

Good luck!

Comment: Sorry, just trying to look at the different configurations and the order you are suggesting.  I created the first job, but not sure what node parameter you are suggesting, a parameter for the build (OS = Win7 Win10 ...) or something else?  For the 2nd job, when you say build triggers, I do not see the parts you are mentioning. Could you add a few images, or text representations?

Comment: Hope it helps. If there are still things that are unclear let me know :)

Comment: I think I found my problem, I am using the 2.x stream, so I do not have the configuration options for jobs that you are using, which is why things seem somewhat different. I added the options to my original question.

Comment: You need to install the Multi-job plugin (in my answer) - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin so you will see the multi-job project. Give it a try if you want :)

Comment: Thanks, I had it installed, but it must not have completely installed as it was not active. I removed it and reinstalled it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I actually found that the Multi-Configuration project will do it, with the execute concurrent builds.  I modified my scripts based on some of the information in your answer, and then ensured I had the concurrent builds on.  It runs builds on all three nodes concurrently.  Might have been a recent fix with original plugins.  I up-voted your answer but am not using it now that the default behaviour works.