# How to add separate parameter for a combination in multiconfiguration project of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testing, multi-configuration

I Have to run a testsuite for following combination, I am using multi configuration project [image]for this. I am looking for something that can allow me to add host_machine for each combination on the fly or statically

[image]

Edit: I am triggering test execution from master to different slave machines. Each configuration in chart can have it's own separate host.

Comment: What is preventing you from setting these up as 12 separate execution on the same job but on a different `slave` each time?

Comment: can you please elaborate little more

Comment: It would really help if you added more information to your question. How many slaves are you having? How many Windows and how many Linux? The diagram suggests atleast 2 `slaves` but there may be more. Are you using `Freestyle jobs` to do this execution? First you need to figure out how many jobs you need to setup and decide how you will string them together to run in parallel or in sequence.

Comment: I have added more information in question. Please see if its helpful.

Comment: Freestyle or pipeline?

Comment: "multi-configuration project" as given in question.

Comment: Please refer this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355992/jenkins-multi-configuration-project-execute-concurrently-on-different-nodes